# Eclipse and SVN question. Please help!

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

This is driving me crazy. I created a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse and later checked the code into a project in SVN. Now when I check out the project into a new workspace using the svn plugin in eclipse it does not prompt the Create New Project Wizard. Apparently this is not prompted if the .project file is checked into the repository. This would have worked ideally if the code is checked out into a Dynamic Web Project again. It is not. I do not see the Server option in the project properties. My guess is it is getting checked out into a JavaEE project. I want to delete the .project from the repository and try but am hesitant as it might screw up the repository. My question is --

- Should I check in the .project file?
- What is the normal usage? Is the project checked out everytime using the New project wizard?
- Why is it that the project I checked in the the one that is checked out different? Did I forget to checkin some files? I understand that the metadata should not be checked in. Are there some others that go along with the .project that needs to be checked in?

Googling does not give me any results. Hope someone ran into this problem here.

Thanks,
- Pav

Comment: Are you sure that your new Eclipse also has JEE features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never upload to repository my IDE dependant files. Main benefits imho:

- Developers can use another IDE if they want (netbeans b.ex).
- Developers can use different project location (folder) if they want.
- Developers can changes project configuration if they want and they do not have to worry about checking in this canges or not.

I use Maven and M2Eclipse plugin (plus integrations: WTP and SVN). With this integrations I get this option menú while browsing my repositories (CVS or SVN) in Eclipse. In netbeans there is similar option.

[image]

Hope this will help you

Comment: I am doing something similar to this in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The type of project (Java, Web, etc.) is stored under the `.settings` folder next to your `.classpath` and `.project` files

Comment: Thanks for this. I am going to remove the .project file from the svn.

Answer (score 0):

I always checked-in the .project file and all metadata files into SVN if it is my own project. Some open source projects (Guava, etc) won't do that, so in that case, I set SVN to ignore the metadata files.